# Grub error with tpm module in Fedora

Tags: fedora, grub, grub2, tpm

I have a problem booting my fedora 36 (in version 35 the same thing happens to me and I have tried to reinstall from 0 with the same result). When I boot the grub I get this error.

```
error ..... tpm.c:148:Unknown TPM error
```

Searching the internet I have found a solution (I think the only one for now) which is to add in the grub entry this line just in front of the first insmod

```
rmmod tpm
```

This works fine for that boot but the change is not persistent and the next time I boot I have to repeat the process again.

I have found the template file that is used in the grub.cfg generation and I have found the line where it does the insmod that I left behind in the rmmod startup. The file is 10_linux in /etc/grub.d
and I added this.

```
  echo " rmmod tpm" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  echo " insmod gzio" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

and then I recreated the configuration file with

```
 # grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and although I see that it uses that template file when generating the cfg it does not include the rmmod.

My question would be where do I have to put that line to make the change persistent between reboots.

I would also like to know if there is a definitive solution to this problem.

Regards